# haskell error on input else

Tags: parsing, haskell, if-statement

having a bit of trouble with the following code. I keep getting an error message "saying parse error on input 'else' ". I cant see what im doing wrong, i have the else statement indented from the if and the syntax inside the statements are correct. Bit of background, its part of an insertion method for 2-3-4 trees, specifically for inserting where a fournode(Root3) needs to be split into its parent. x y and z are the values in the fournode while c1 - c4 are its child nodes.  have looked at other questions on here about these types of errors but couldn't find anything useful :( Anyone have any ideas?

> `insert t (Root1 a left right)
>           | t <= a =
>               case left of
>
>                   (Root3 x y z c1 c2 c3 c4) -> if t <= y 
>                                                    then Root2 y a (insert t (Root1 x c1 c2) (Root1 z c3 c4) right
>                                                    else Root2 y a (Root1 x c1 c2) (insert t (Root1 z c3 c4)) right
>
>            _ ->  Root1 a (insert t(left)) (right)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other errors, but immediately I can see that your parenthesis aren't matched....  Take a look at the parens in the `then`.  The compiler doesn't expect the `else` until after the then clause is finished, but the missing end paren is keeping this from happening.

Comment: could you please explain? i dont see anything wrong with the parenthesis in this code. I should mention that this is only part of my insert method, but its the part thats not working. The code compiles fine and runs without it, but obviously as a result the fournode doesn't split properly

Comment: Count your parens, there are more opening than closing.  In particular, after the `then`, I see an opening paren before `insert`, and although there are some open-and-close parens after, this particular one doesn't end before the `else`.

Comment: ok so i added the missing paren and that did the trick, but now im getting a similar error on the next line " _ ->  Root1 a (insert t(left)) (right) " and i really cant see anything wrong with it? pretty sure my logic is correct at least :p

Comment: You need to put the same whitespace before each item in a `case`-`of`.  That means that the `(Root3 x y z c1 c2 c3 c4) ->` and `_ ->` need to be indented to the same place, and they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation has mixed tabs and spaces, which is a big no-no: indentation is very significant in Haskell, and you want to make sure that what you see is the same as what the compiler sees. Just because a tab looks about as wide as eight spaces doesn't mean you can put one in instead of the eight spaces.

I recommend you fix this to use spaces-only, make sure things are lined up correctly, and then if you're still having issues ask a new question.